# Get rid of urllib not defined error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Keep getting the same thing every time I try to run the program, `urllib` is not defined.  How do I get rid of it?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError

aname = 'http://website.com'
try:
    htm = urlopen(aname + '/').read()
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
```

Yes, I do have another problem I sure wish I could figure out as well, I can't get `bs4` to install correctly, it keep trying to install to Python 2.7, which I don't have any 2.7 interpreter installed, only 3.4.3 is installed on the computer.  I have a strange feeling that might be causing me some other issues as well with some some other programs.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have the line `from urllib.error import HTTPError` or the `from urllib.request import urlopen` *doesn't* mean that `urrlib` is available as a name in your script.

This is specified [in the documentation for the `import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) statement specifically in the section dealing with the `from` form; see the examples there to see what becomes available and what doesn't.

Therefore, when you `except`:

```
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
```

it fails when trying to find the name `urrlib`. Either just use `HTTPError`, as imported and bound to your namespace, in the `except` clause:

```
except HTTPError as e:
```

or, if you *need* the name for `urllib` available in your namespace, `import urllib` instead of `from urllib.error import HTTPError` and use the original `except` clause.

As for the installation issue, try using `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Comment: That appears to have taken care of the urllib problem.  As for the bs4 I've tried installing it both ways...pip3 install python3 beautilfulsoup4.  Doing it this way all I get is an error 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirements python3.  I also tried...pip3 install beautifulsoup4 and it comes up as says the requirement is already satisfied and shows it being in usr/local/lib/python2.7.

Comment: That appears to have taken care of the urllib problem.  As for the bs4 I've tried installing it both ways...pip3 install python3 beautilfulsoup4.  Doing it this way all I get is an error 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirements python3.  I also tried...pip3 install beautifulsoup4 and it comes up as says the requirement is already satisfied and shows it being in usr/local/lib/python2.7.

Comment: @confused Not sure about your `pip` issues, it doesn't make sense to me for it to be saying that beautifulsoup4 exists in the directory for `2.7`, try going through Python with `python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4`.